# Манипуляции с генерированными данными Jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть примерные функции:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var v1 = 0;
    var v2 = 0;
    $('#add').bind('click', function () {
        $('#list').append('<button id="'+v1+'" class="c1">'+tp+'</button>');
        $('#'+(v1-1)).removeClass('c1');
        v1++;
        v2++;
    });

    $('#list button').bind('click', function () {
        $('#'+(v2)).removeClass('c1');
        $(this).attr('class', 'c1');
        v2 = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});

<span id="add">+</span> <span id="list"></span>
```

То есть есть возможность создать элемент и переключаться между списком созданных элементов. Но возникла проблема со вторым событием: $('#list button').bind('click' ...
Оно просто напросто не реагирует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

невроятно заезженная тема! используйте делегирование:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'button', function () {
    ...
});
```

- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал.